# The Makeup of the Pentaquark

Tags: standard-model, quarks, pentaquarks

Why is it that when they have the artist's rendition of the Pentaquark it shows two downs, two ups, and one anti-strange quark? Is this or is this just for show? Follow up to this question: if this configuration is just for show, what is the Pentaquark truly made of?

Answer (score 7):

A pentaquark is a particle made of five quarks. "Penta" means 'five' in Greek. Technically it could be made of any combination of quarks/antiquarks, though subject to some **restrictions** - see below.

Quarks are bound by the *strong force*. In the same way as the electromagnetic force sees the (electric) charge of particles and causes interactions only within charged matter, the strong force has an associated *colour*. Only coloured particles interact via the strong force. There are three colours: red, blue and green. These are just names, they have absolutely no optical/visual meaning - you could have called them 1, 2 and 3.

The defining feature of the strong interaction is that a *free* particle held together by it can only exist if it is colour neutral: i.e. if the total colour is 0. This can by either having, say, a blue quark being balanced by blue anti-quark, or by having all three colours at the same time - red+blue+green gives white=0, in analogy to visible light. This is known as *colour confinement*. The strong force is so powerful that particles subject to it cannot break free; when the colour charge is 0, however, they cease to feel it so they can move around and exist independently.

Quarks have colours. If you want a pentaquark you need to mix quarks and antiquarks of the correct colour in order to obtain an overall colour neutral system. E.g. a red, blue and green quark + a red and an anti-red quark. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentaquark) for pictures. *EDIT: As the comments have stressed, this is actually the only viable configuration of the pentaquark: 4 quarks and an antiquark*.

They usually show up, down and strange quarks because they are the lightest quarks and therefore the most likely to be produced. If they ever find a pentaquark (like they are claiming now at CERN), it is highly probably that it is made of u, d and s. You'd need higher energies to create heavier quarks.

Comment: *"Technically it could be made of any combination of quarks/antiquarks, though subject to some restrictions."* Er ... the restrictions are pretty important. It's really only possible for it to be four quarks and one anti-quark or the other way around.

Comment: What dmckee said is true, and comes from Baryon number being 1/3 for quarks, -1/3 for anti-quarks, and a whole number for any physical particle. (And quite important)

Comment: Yeah well I explain the restrictions later on, I just wanted to stress the number five. I'll add a small edit

Answer (score 5):

In Scientific American, they said it was this specific grouping as illustrated, though with arbitrary coloring.  It briefly stated how it must involve which quarks based on decay channels. I lost my hardcopy of the magazine so I can't easily look upmthe quotation now.

I think it was *not* as you describe though... 
[image]

Yea, it's in Wikipedia now.

> In July 2015, the LHCb collaboration identified pentaquarks in the Λ0
>   b→J/ψK−
>   p channel, which represents the decay of the bottom lambda baryon (Λ0
>   b) into a J/ψ meson (J/ψ), a kaon (K−
>   ) and a proton (p). The results showed that sometimes, instead of decaying directly into mesons and baryons, the Λ0
>   b decayed via intermediate pentaquark states. The two states, named P+
>   c(4380) and P+
>   c(4450), had individual statistical significances of 9 σ and 12 σ, respectively, and a combined significance of 15 σ — enough to claim a formal discovery. The analysis ruled out the possibility that the effect was caused by conventional particles. The two pentaquark states were both observed decaying strongly to J/ψp, hence must have a valence quark content of **two up quarks, a down quark, a charm quark, and an anti-charm quark (uudcc)**, making them charmonium-pentaquarks.

(Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/185519/if-mesons-were-stable-could-they-form-atoms/185562#185562) for a quick look into exotic hadrons. These particles mostly(at least so far) are very unstable appears for a short time and decay into another particles, hadrons and mesons. Hadrons made of 3 quarks and mesons one quark and its anti-matter. These unstable particles(resonances) have a quark content based on initial and final state particles.
$$
\Lambda_b^0\rightarrow Resonance \rightarrow J/\psi p K^-
$$
$J/\psi$ has a charmonium quark content $c \bar{c}$ where proton $uud$. And our penta-quark has five-leafed clover.
[image]

But this not as easy as seen. There are lots of possibilities about quark content and you need to eliminate the others by technical analyzes. I strongly recommend the [LCHb article](http://lhcb-public.web.cern.ch/lhcb-public/Welcome.html#Penta) for further details.

Today, researchers are confident about the exotic state, pentaquark and its form of quarks. What they should do further is studying the "internal mechanism" of the particle. I mean quark interactions of the particle. Further studies will be about whether this particle is tightly bound with strong gluonic interactions or softly bound via pion exchange as I showed in my previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

The recent high-energy experiments have found the true pentaquark model of the proton: four quarks and an anti-quark. In fact these quarks may be highly-energetic electrons. Proton is pentaquark.

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340741231_The_Geometry_of_the_Proton_and_the_Tetryen_Shape

https://vixra.org/abs/1708.0146